# How to read block of lines in python only if a condition is met?

Tags: python

I need to create a script that reads four lines and, if a condition is met, reads the next four lines in the file, and so on. If the condition isn't met, the script must restart the test from the second line of the previously read block. Therefore, the first line of what was the would be next block becomes the new fourth line. For instance I want to retrieve all the blocks that sum 4 from the following file.

```
printf "1\n1\n1\n1\n2\n1\n1\n1\n1" > file1.txt #In BASH
```

Lines from 1 to 4 sum 4, so they produce a positive results. Lines from 5 to 8 sum 5,so they produce a negative results and the sum must be redone starting in the 6th line and ending in the 9th, which sum 4 and therefore throw a positive results. I'm aware that I could do something like this,

```
with open("file1.txt") as infile:
  while not EOF:
    lines = []
    for i in range(next N lines):
        lines.append(infile.readline())
    make_the_sum(lines)
```

but this will move the reader four lines and will make impossible to go backwards if the sum is larger than 4. How can I achieve this  effect? Consider that my files are large and I can't load them whole in memory.

Comment: But you can load the 4 you have read, and re-use them as need be, correct?

Comment: Just store the most recent 4 lines then.

Comment: what happens when you have less than four lines left to read?

Answer (score 0):

I am simplifying by ignoring the end of file issue. You could use tell and seek to handle recovering an earlier position (you could save as many positions as you required in a list, say:

```
>>> with open('testmedium.txt') as infile:
...     times = 0
...     EOF = 0
...     while not EOF:
...         pos = infile.tell()
...         print(f"\nPosition is {pos}")
...         lines = []
...         for i in range(4):
...             lines.append(infile.readline())
...         [print(l[:20]) for l in lines]
...         if times==0 and '902' in lines[0]:
...             times = 1
...             infile.seek(pos)
...         elif '902' in lines[0]:
...             break

Position is 0
271,848,690,44,511,5
132,427,793,452,85,6
62,617,183,843,456,3
668,694,659,691,242,

Position is 125
902,550,177,290,828,
326,603,623,79,803,5
803,949,551,947,71,8
661,881,124,382,126,

Position is 125
902,550,177,290,828,
326,603,623,79,803,5
803,949,551,947,71,8
661,881,124,382,126,

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will read lines into a "cache" (just a list) and do some work on the cached lines when the cache has four lines.  If the test passes, the cache gets cleared.  If the test fails, the cache is updated to contain only the last three lines of the cache.  You can do additional work in the if-else blocks as necessary.

```
def passes_test(lines, target_value=4):
    return sum([int(line) for line in lines]) == target_value

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    cached = []
    for line in f:
        cached.append(line)
        if len(cached) == 4:
            if passes_test(cached):
                cached = []
            else:
                cached = cached[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn has suggested,

```
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    rd = lambda: int(next(f))
    try:
        a, b, c, d = rd(), rd(), rd(), rd()
        if a + b + c + d == 4:
            # found a block
            a, b, c, d = rd(), rd(), rd(), rd()
        else:
            # nope
            a, b, c, d = b, c, d, rd()
    except StopIteration:
        # found end of file
```

Comment: I tried you solution but it must have a mistake. It only verifies the first block of four number and then stops.